# When solving differential equations, does the solution order matters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Example with a repeated root solution: is $\mathbf{y}_1=\mathbf{C}_1.e^{x/2}.x ,$$ \mathbf{y}_2 = \mathbf{C}_2e^{x/2}$ the same thing as $\mathbf{y}_2 =\mathbf{C}_1.e^{x/2}.x,\mathbf{y}_1=\mathbf{C}_2.e^{x/2}$? Or more generally,when you're solving second order differential equations,when does the order of the solutions matter at all? Thanks!

Comment: If you have a repeated root solution, then only one of your solutions will actually be a solution to the differential equation - the other one would be of the form $Axe^{x/2}$ where $A$ is a constant. Otherwise, the ordering of your general solutions is arbitary - it is usually better to just give both "solutions" as part of one solution/function (i.e. we would just write the solution as $y=C_1 e^{x/2} + C_2 e^{x/2}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew mentions, it is completely arbitrary.

Lets reverse engineer your problem and show this. We have:

$$\tag 1 y''(x)-y'(x)+ \dfrac{1}{4}y(x) = 0$$

The roots of CP are given by:

$$m^2 - m + \dfrac{1}{4} = 0 \rightarrow m_{1,2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

So, we have a double root, thus we can choose solutions as:

$$\tag 2 y_1 = c_1 e^{x/2}+c_2 e^{x/2} x$$

or

$$\tag 3 y_2 = +c_1 e^{x/2} x + c_2 e^{x/2}$$

or other variants with negative constants.

Lets verify these two variants of these solutions.

Solution 1:

- $y_1 = c_1 e^{x/2}+c_2 e^{x/2} x$
- $y'_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} c_1e^{x/2} + c_2e^{x/2}\left(\dfrac{x}{2} + 1\right)$
- $y''_1 = \dfrac{1}{4} e^{x/2} \left(c_2 (x+4)+c_1 \right)$
- Substituting back into $(1)$ yields:

$y_1''-y_1'+ \dfrac{1}{4}y_1 = \left(\dfrac{1}{4} e^{x/2} (c_2 (x+4)+c_1)\right) -\left(\dfrac{1}{2} c_1e^{x/2} + c_2e^{x/2}\left(\dfrac{x}{2} + 1\right)\right) + \dfrac{1}{4}\left(c_1 e^{x/2}+c_2 e^{x/2} x\right) = 0$

So, solution $1$ works. Repeat this for $(3)$, that is $y_2$, and verify that it also solves the DEQ to convince yourself.

Comment: Your example was the second question of my exam today, who am I to by pass your answer after such sign? Thanks very much for your help, that was perfect! @Amzoti

Comment: @matt_zarro: Glad to hear that, I think (hope it did not ruin the fun of the examp for you)! ;-) Regards